# Programmatically, what needs to be done to use X.509 Client Certificates in your calls to SAP?

Tags: c#, iis, x509certificate, bapi

I'm currently using User ID / password basic authentication. What do I need to do, in order to start using X.509 Digital Certificates?

My web application is written in C# and is running on top of IIS.

**Additional info:** I'll be invoking BAPIs/ zBAPIs with code generated by Rafael My SAP Proxy Visual Studio Plug-in: http://tools.rafaelc.net/default.aspx?id=72. It automatically generates a proxy code.

I'm wondering wether this generated code can be changed to use client certificates and, in this case, what do I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use client-certificates.

On the AS-ABAP-Serverside:
First you need upload your CA to transaction strust (Directory SSL-Server-Standard).
Secondly view VUSREXTID needs to be maintained (see https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Basis/How+to+configure+client+certificate+logon+to+AS+ABAP).
I recommend to upload the client-certificate, so the view is maintained with the correct DN of the certificate and the issuer-certificate.
The last step is to change the authentication-procedure for the service-node (transaction sicf) to "Required with SSL Certificate":
[image: SLL Client authentication service]